# Matlab - Creating a characteristic for Peak and Shelving filter

Tags: matlab, filters, filter-design, infinite-impulse-response

I have designed few shelving and peak filter. And I have calculated the a, b coeficients for several gains for these filters. Now I would like to create some kind of characteristic in Matlab so I could present my design of these filters?

Something like this for shelving filter 
[image]

Comment: freqz - but really, this is a programming question

Comment: i'm just curious, what *are* your findings?

Comment: I added my characteristics for filters below.

Comment: but what did you find?  and what do you mean by "characteristics"?

Comment: I just wanted to know if my calculation were right for these filters. By characteristics I mean these graphs below, I do not know how to say it in English

Comment: you wanted to visualize the frequency response to confirm that it has peaks or shelves?

Comment: Yes but no to confirm, but to know if calculated coeficients for filters were right. From these visulations I know that filters work good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use [**fvtool**](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/signal/ref/fvtool.html) in MATLAB:

```
fvtool(b,a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @jojek I managed to create some characteristics for my filters.

Low shelving filter

[image: Low shelving filter]

High shelving filter

[image: High shelving filter]

Peak filter - bandwidth

[image: Peak filter - bandwidth]

Peak filter - gain

[image: Peak filter - gain]